# Jquery slow reaction time

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, visual-web-developer

I try to use the jQuery for my header animation, the animation slows down after I added:

```
else if (headeranimated && $(this).scrollTop() > 1200)
else if (headeranimated2 && headeranimated && $(this).scrollTop() < 1000)
```

I have to wait a couple of seconds for the second part of animation. Is there anything wrong with this code?

Thank you

```js
 // header animation
var headeranimated2 = false;
var headeranimated = false;
var headeranimated3 = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 800) {
    if (!headeranimated && $(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
      $('#headerpattern').animate({
        left: "-40%"
      }, 800);
      headeranimated = true;
    } else if (headeranimated && $(this).scrollTop() > 1200) {
      $('#headerpattern').animate({
        top: "-20%"
      }, 200);
      headeranimated2 = true;
    } else if (headeranimated2 && headeranimated && $(this).scrollTop() < 1000) {
      $('#headerpattern').animate({
        top: "0"
      }, 200);
      headeranimated2 = false;
      headeranimated3 = true
    } else if (headeranimated3 && !headeranimated2 && $(this).scrollTop() < 400) {
      $('#headerpattern').animate({
        left: "0"
      }, 800);
      headeranimated = false;
      headeranimated3 = false;
    }
  } else {
    if (!headeranimated && $(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
      $('#headerpattern').animate({
        top: "-8%"
      }, 1200);
      headeranimated = true;
    } else if (headeranimated && $(this).scrollTop() < 400) {
      $('#headerpattern').animate({
        top: "0"
      }, 800);
      headeranimated2 = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. you are calling the scroll listener which occurs evry moment while you are scrolling. but you also play an animation which is relatevly slow to scroll. when you call the scroll listener by scrolling, you create multiple nimations calls which try to play all at once (and that is why it slows down the ui).

**the solution**: if animation still played - don't scroll

```
var animScroll;

$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if (animScroll) return;

    if ($(window).width() > 800)
    {       
       if (!headeranimated && $(this).scrollTop() > 500) 
       {
         animScroll = true;
         $('#headerpattern').animate({ left: "-40%"}, 800, function()
         {
            animScroll = false;
         });

         headeranimated = true;
     }

     // rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

A `scroll` even is an event the is emitted continuously while scrolling, so it will be triggered multiple times a second while you are scrolling.

Whenever you call `.animate` for an element, the animation is added to a queue. And the animations are executed one after the other, in the order they where added to the queue. As your animations have a duration of in a range of `200` to `1200` you might result in an animation queue that has a duration of several seconds.

One solution would be to call `.stop()` before you call `.animate`:

```
$('#headerpattern').stop().animate(....)
```

But this might break your desired effect.

Another solution would be to check if there is an animation that is currently running and if so, then do not start a new animation. But this will have some kind of *stop and go*  or *delay* effect.

Comment: yea, this seems like the easiest solution here, but i'm just wondering will it affect the performance(speed for slower computer) if I just leave the scroll function keep on running?

Comment: yea, .stop() does affect the animation because it's not so touchpad friendly.

Comment: @ZhengWang Well the problem will the longer the user scrolls continuously the bigger the animation queue becomes. Even if it is not a performance issue, your effect will be blocked for a long time before it will work _correct_ again. Especially with touch devices this might be a huge problem. Generally I would say that using `.animation`  for this kind of effects is not feasible.

Comment: Do you mean for this specific situation or for scrolling in general?

Comment: @ZhengWang `.animation()` does not work well in combination with events that are triggered in short intervals like `mousemove` or `scroll`.