# .animate(); in Javascript is Freezing for a second

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am having problems with `.animate()` in Javascript. I am using it to automatically scroll to an element in a div whitch is working. The problem I have is that after a few milliseconds the scrolling freezes for a second or so and then continues at that point where it should already had animated to and then it continues animating without any problems.

The scrollable div contains about 36 divs with the width of 75 px and in the background is a dynamically generated SVG graph. To animate the div I using

```
parent.stop(true, false).animate({
            scrollLeft: offsetToLeft
        }, 50*Math.abs(elementsToSkipp), function (element, index) {
            //Show highlight the element and refresh data
            return false;
        }.bind(this, forecastElement[0], index));
```

The `return false;` and `.stop(true, false)` is from Stackoverflow, but it did not really fixed my issue. Help is very appreciated.

EDIT:
I only experience this lag on mobile devices (iOS, Android), there is no such lag on a Desktop PC.

Thanks,

David

Comment: Are you doing anything else at the same time? Ajax call returning data, altering the DOM?

Comment: Can we have more code to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: @Ludovic Sorry, I cant show more code, because it is under NDA.

Comment: @epascarello No, not really. Before the animation I am calculating `offsetToLeft`, thats all. Then when it comes to the animation part I can see a lag. Did you experienced a similar issue in the past?

Comment: You might want to investigate [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/). It's more-or-less a drop-in replacement for the jQuery animation code, and it generally performs much better.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you are running your animation **as a response to a scroll event**. here is a post wich solves this kind of problem (including code): [Jquery slow reaction time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101208/jquery-slow-reaction-time/27101318#27101318)

Comment: No, the animation is a result of a tap event. When the user taps on a button the scrollview moves the element that should be shown to the left border of the screen.

Comment: can you make sure that the tap event raised only once?

Comment: mandez zaig Yes, the function is only called once. I also should point out, that the lagg only occur on mobile devices (iOS an Android). There is no such lag on Desktop PCs.

Comment: in that case, please replace the **bind** method with **on** method

Comment: @yackovmandeszaig that's not the jQuery `.bind()` method, it's `Function.prototype.bind()`